# Display Google Custom Search results on your own site

Tags: google-programmable-search-engine

Is there a way for Google's Custom Search engine to show it's results on a page on your website?

On a custom page which you put on your server, so you can still display ads and links to pages in your site together with the search results?

Comment: Have you read the documentation / manual?

Answer (score 2):

You can host the results from a CSE as an iframe on your site:

- http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70330

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Bing, which has an XML api and doesn't charge for an unbranded search as google does.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this - This may not work as is, but play around with it till it does

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" onSubmit="googleSearch(this)">
    <input name="XXX"  type="text"  value="SEARCH ..." >
    <input type="submit" >
    </form>


<script>
function googleSearch(thisG){
thisG.value="site:http://mysite.com"+thisG.XXX.value
</script>
```

}